# How did these unregistered users write answers?

Tags: support, status-completed, answers, user-accounts

For those who have enough reputation to see deleted posts, you'll notice that [this answer](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/a/9547/5) was written by an unregistered user named [boss](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/users/5868/boss). Very soon after, we also got [this answer](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/a/9706/5) by an unregistered user named [Josh](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/users/6025/josh).

However, we supposedly banned unregistered users from posting, per this request from earlier this year: [Does the Matter Modeling community want to ban unregistered users from asking questions?](https://mattermodeling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/317/5)

The answer suggesting to ban unregistered posts in general got a net score of 9, while the answer suggesting to only ban unregistered users for questions and ***not*** for answers got a net score of 0.

How were these unregistered users able to post answers?

Comment: Interesting that the question got 1 upvote and the answer got 2 (none from me, probably because the answer wasn't satisfactory: unregistered users should have been banned from answering at the same time as they were banned from asking; but it was almost 1.5 years ago that I made the decision not to upvote).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Unregistered posting of answers has now been disabled on Matter Modeling Stack Exchange.** (We'd already enabled requiring registration to ask, as of the previous request linked in your post.)

It looks like there was some confusion when another CM handled the request to disable unregistered posting in a previous meta post. As you note, the body of the previous post asked that unregistered posting be disabled for both questions and answers, and the highest-scoring answer agreed with this request. However, the *title* of that post only mentioned preventing unregistered users from asking questions – so when the [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) tag was added to that request, it created an internal ticket for us with the same title.

There are multiple site settings that control the ability of users to participate in the site as an unregistered user. One such setting controls whether the site requires registration to ask questions, while another setting controls whether anonymous users can post answers (or ask questions) without registering first. Presumably due to the confusion I mentioned above, only the first site setting was changed, but not the second.

After checking with the mods whether unregistered posting of answers is still a problem on Matter Modeling Stack Exchange, I've gone ahead and disabled unregistered posting of answers as well. If anyone encounters issues with this, please let us know.

Comment: Thanks so much V2Blast! I see now that the title only mentioned questions. Thanks for pointing that out! I do wonder though, why this post and the other one had the "status-review" tag for so long before becoming "status-completed", because [it seems that it got done so quickly on Mechanics.SE](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/62295357#62295357).

Comment: Not sure about the previous request, but in this case, it was partly due to the Community Team being quite busy over the last few weeks, and partly due to the time it took to first investigate what happened with the last request and then communicate with the mods (including giving them time to respond).